# import MySQL5.5 databases

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I recently upgraded to Windows server 2008 and wanted to transfer over my MySQL databases.

All my files moved to Windows.old, I moved over my "Data" table from Program Files / MySQL 5.5 / Data to the new program files of my current windows and restarted the MySQL service but phpmyadmin is unable to detect my databases whatsoever.

I'm in a state of panic because I've lost all my crucial databases, please help.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Always, always backup key files before performing any sort of upgrade :-(

Comment: I've learned my lesson from this, but I thought for sure it would back up in the Data folder :(

Answer (score 0):

The good news is, if you're using the same version and release of MySQL now as you were before, your data is probably not lost.  You just have to sort out why MySQL cannot find the database files.

If you can get the MySQL command line program to start, try running the query

> show variables like 'datadir';

See if the data directory is set where you expect it to be.  If not, edit my.ini (it may be taking a my.ini from a location you don't expect).

If you cannot get the MySQL Windows Service to start, check the Windows event log.

Comment: Ok, the application directory was wrong as you said.. thank you.

one more issue, it says incorrect login on php my admin and on mysqld command line yet my password is exactly the same as the old one. wth

Comment: Error: Access denied for user root@localhost (using password YES)  I re-ran the instance config and it said the root pass was correct and it let me continue then it error'd out on "Applying security settings" and I disabled the firewall too. no-go.

Comment: Found all the databases, found out why it wasn't accepting password (directory was set to Appdata originally and I set it t program files directory) but service still unexpectedly stops with error 1067 ;-(

Comment: Is there anything in the event log after the service stops?